# How do I quickly move between 2 local installations and keep them in sync?

Tags: localhost, local-installation, development-strategy, remote

I'm a designer working on my first CMS website. I like to develop on my netbook at the coffee shop, but recently I've been starting to get into graphics heavy content stuff that would be easier to work on, on my desktop.

What's the best way to do this?

My thought process was, that I could install my database on my Dreamhost server, and then work on the actual wordpress and theme stuff locally, having it point to the remote database, and push and pull from git to keep stuff in sync.

But I've been told in other threads that this is a bad idea.

Reconfiguring the database each time seems like a real pain in the ass. And waiting for my Dreamhost server to show changes after every edit and upload to FTP seems like a slow way to work.

I have very little backend experience so I'm trying to find the most straightforward ways of doing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I might not be getting this. The PC is for graphics stuff the laptop for coding. Or you want both to have a WP install with the same db and theme changes? In that case work locally, use XAMPP and use Duplicator, then after that either just copy over the pure theme files assuming you will be working with dummy content that once filled won't be needing db changes. Also no lag when working locally. Just copy files from one theme dir to the other over the local network. Check out http://learnwebcode.com/learn-wordpress/ for getting round WP as your first CMS. Is this what your question is about?

Comment: @lowtechsun No not really. I will be coding on both my PC and laptop. When I say that I'm getting into "graphics heavy work", I mean that I will be producing graphics and organizing a large number of picture files in order to fill the website content in, which I will be do while simultaneously coding and building the structure that the content will go into.

Comment: You need some CVS software for sync like GIT,SVN

Comment: I already have that but that doesn't handle database export/re-import,  and local configuration in an automated way.